# Set value in message.properties file from grails service

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I want to set values to `message.properties` file.

I have already done it in java like the following:

```
    Properties emailErrorMsgProp = new Properties();

    emailErrorMsgProp.load(new FileInputStream("grails-app/i18n/messages.properties"));

    emailErrorMsgProp.setProperty("ma_email_error",result.callStatusMsg.toString());

    emailErrorMsgProp.store(new FileOutputStream("grails-app/i18n/messages.properties"), null);
```

I also want to make it language specific.i have language specific properties files.

I would like to do the same thing in grails Service, but how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def writeToProps(key, value) {
    new File("grails-app/i18n/messages.properties").withWriterAppend { out ->
      out.writeLine "\n${key}=${value}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html).